# FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file on line number 1

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone please help me identify why this code isn't working? It's copied directly from a youtube tutorial so I can't see where I've gone wrong!

Thank you!

I basically want to create matrix rain, but my own version of symbols within it. Would someone be able to correctly identify what's wrong with this code? I have tried to input it into http://phptester.net/

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Matrix Rain</title>
        <style>
            /*basic resets */
            * {margin:0; padding: 0;}
            /* adding a black bg to the background to make things clearer */
            body {background: black;}
            canvas {display: block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var c = document.getElementbyId("c");
            var ctx = c.getCont("2d");

            //making the canvas full screen
            c.height = window.innerHeight;
            c.width = windows.innerWidth;

            var ganoti = "诶比西迪艾弗艾尺艾勒艾娜吉吾艾儿"

            //converting the string into an array of single characters
            chinese = chinese.split ("");

            var font_size = 10;
            var columns = c.width/font_size; //number of columns for rain

            //an array of drops - one for column
            var drops = [];

            //x below is the x coordinate
            //1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
            for (var = x; x < columns; x++)
                drops[x] = 1;

            //drawing the characters
            function draw () {
                //Black BG for the canvas
                //translucent BG to show trail

                ctx.fillStyle - "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0, c.wdith, c.height);

                ctx.fillstyle = "DB7093";
                ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";

                //looping over drops
                for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
                    var text = ganoti[Math.floor(Math.random()*ganoti.lenth)];

                    //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
                    ctx.fillText(text, i*font_size, drops[i]*font_size);

                    //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed 
                    screen // it should be in comment line
                    //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the 
                    Y axis // it should be in comment line

                    if (drops[i]*font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
                        drops[i] = 0;

                    //incrementing Y coordinate
                    drops[i]++
                }

            }
            setInterval(draw, 33);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `}` closing tags after the `</html>`?

Comment: `for (var = x; x < columns; x++)` is a syntax error, you shouldn't have a `=` between `var` and `x` (you probably meant `var x = 0`). The error suggests some *other* problem with how you're doing this, and certainly those `} }` at the end are in the wrong place, but that's the first error that comes up when using this as HTML. There are also errors where you've added line breaks in single-line comments, and `getElementbyId` instead of `getElementById` (note the capitalization), etc. Either the tutorial is very poor, or (with respect) you need to be more careful copying it.

Comment: There are 4 or 5 syntax errors, redundant double } at the end, incorrect for loop, incorrect getElementById , unknown function getCont...

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was copying.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMpybYZICjM

Answer (score -1):

`phptester.net` requires PHP, your code is HTML, besides has redundant double `}` in the end.

Comment: Thank you I have tried in html now and it still doesn't seem to work.